# Are interrupt signals dispatched during fread() and fwrite() library calls?

Tags: c, file, interrupt, file-handling

On Linux, the C standard library calls `fread` and `fwrite` execute the system call equivalents, `read` and `write`.

The man pages for the system calls mention interrupts, saying that a short write may occur with `errno` set to `EINTR`. However, the man pages for the library functions say nothing about interrupts. So, can interrupts occur during these library functions?

https://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite

Comment: [man 7 linux signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) is a good place for understanding signal interruption during syscall.

Answer (score 7):

Interrupts can occur during the [`fread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) and [`fwrite()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwrite.html) functions (and during the [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) and [`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) system calls  — there's no way to stop that.  However, it is not so clear what happens if an interrupt occurs — whether the signal is delivered or not.  It depends on how your application (thread?) is set up to handle interrupts.

- If it ignores them, then there'll be no effect on `fread()` or `fwrite()`.
- If it has default handling, the program will stop; the functions will not return.
- If your signal handler exits or use [`siglongjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/siglongjmp.html) (or [`longjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/longjmp.html)), then the system call won't return.
- If your handler returns, it will depend on what you specified to [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) when you set up the handler.

  - `SA_RESTART` means that the underlying `read` or `write` will be retried
  - No `SA_RESTART` will mean that the `read` or `write` will terminate — possibly with a short read or write, or possibly with an error and `errno` set to EINTR.
  - If the system call indicates failure, it is probable that `fread()` and `fwrite()` will report failure too if no data was read or written before the interrupt occurred.
  - If some data was read or written, you'll probably get the short read or write response.